# QML/D text editor and basic considerations

Tags: c++, qt4, text-editor, d, qml

I am going to code a text/code editor (GUI with QML and the rest in D*). But I have several problems:

- I code the GUI with QML and C++ and then I connect it with a D-Backend for formatting etc. purposes. What is the best way to connect different Languages? Pipes, Sockets or in D the ability to use C++ Libraries?
- IMHO rich text is used to format the text (in most cases). How is it possible to edit this "markup" in an easy way?? Is the formated code like a background image and the user edits an opaque non-formated-text?
- Are there common techniques?

*Because QML is cool, platform indepedent and fast. On the other hand D is powerful and easy to use.

Comment: One question is left: Are there common editor techniques to edit formatted text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you might know, there is [QtD](https://bitbucket.org/qtd/repo), Qt binding for D. It's not production ready right now, but it might be some day.

Another option would be connecting C++ and D, through C wrapper. This is the most commonly used way of interacting between C++ and D.

`extern(C++)` interfaces are specific to DigitalMars C++ compiler on Windows and are very limited, so that probably wouldn't help with your problem.

Also you might want to look at [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/). It's a tool automatically generating glue code for interaction of other languages with C++. It supports D.

If performance is not an issue communications with D code could work through sockets or pipes.

Comment: Thanks! QtD is not really an option because I want to use QML (>4.7) and AFAIK this is not supported yet.

Comment: @NaN QML is usually used for web apps.  So, is this going to be some kind of web app?

Comment: QML for web apps? Who creates Webpages by using C++ or at least Qt? I want to code a desktop-program like Notepad++, Scite,... because I don't like the existing ones - they are slow, not powerful enough or look too oldstyle! So I want a fast, powerful and beautiful alternative.

Answer (score 2):

QML isn't for WebApp. It s QtQuick Markup Language. The 'new' way to do UI at Qt. And QWidget will probably be deprecated in favor of QML in Qt5.

I've try to do the same thing. But i fear that qml isn't ready yet to do things like that. Most element available today are just good enought to draw image, rectangle, listview, one line text input and do transition.

I was trying to achieve that by coloring with python and pygments, too slow, using html3.2 style to do that isn't the right way. But it's the only way to style text in qml textedit. ;(

QtQuick 2.0 should bring better text control.

Comment: Yes, you're right! QML isn't ready (yet). I'll try it by the old way and hope that I can use QML next year.